# Create redirect for changing destination

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect

Is it possible to create a 301 redirection where the name of the destination has a part in it, that changes every once in a while?

In my example I have to redirect a page to another one. However, the destination URL has a date attached to it, that sometimes is being changed.

The destination page (it's actually a PDF) looks similar to this:

example.com/this-is-a-recurring-event-**05-04-19.pdf**

The bold part changes sometimes, so I cannot simply write a redirection to that specific page. Is it possible to use some kind of wildcard within the destination?

Comment: That would be possible, sure. _But_ : That does not make any sense at all! Consider that a 301 is a _permanent_ redirection. So clients cache it. They will never again send a request to the server for that URL once they have been redirected. What you probably want is a 302, which is a temporary redirection, which does _not_ get cached.

Comment: And: a "wildcard within the destination" also makes no sense here: You want to redirect to a specific target... How should the redirection logic know where (to what target) you actually _do_ want the redirection to happen? It cannot somehow magically guess that...

Comment: I assume what you are looking for is not a redirection at all, but a simple routing script: by means of an internal rewrite you redirect all incoming requests to that script (for example a php script). That script allows to read the actual object from wherever you like (however it is actually called), for example by scanning a file system folder and picking the most recent document in there. Then it "forwards" that object to the requesting client, specifying the correct mime type of the content.

Comment: @arkascha The wildcard should take the first match and ignore all other matches that come after that (since the name without the date is already unique, that would work).

Comment: Sorry, but that is not what rewriting and redirecting is meant for. Please consider the last third comment I made above which explains the standard (and clean) way of implementing such task. Keep in mind that you should _not_ directly expose access to folders where you store objects inside. Various reasons why you want to have a controlling logic handling such requests. Even if you can succeed calling some folder scanning extension to the rewriting engine (you certainly _can_ ) even then I would consider that an ugly solution.

Comment: Thank you for all the comments and considerations.